# How to get the max number in a column up to a cell Google Sheets and excel

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

This code would be in B8:

```
=if(C8="","",1+max(C5:C7))
```

Then in B9 I would have this:

```
=if(C9="","",1+max(C5:C8))
```

and eventually ending with:

```
=if(C8="","",1+max(C5:C365))
```

I copied the code to each cell but it auto changes the C5 to correspond with the new cell.

I started manually changing each cell so the MAX Function will range from C5 and up but by the time I got to row 40, I found myself on this page. All cells need the max function to start at C5 and then stop at the cell to the right and above.

Is there a better way than copying the code cell by cell and changing the C# and changing it to a C5?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Kyle, offering help would be more efficient and effective if you were to share a sample spreadsheet with data in Column C and at least the first, say, 20 rows of B filled in manually. If you choose to do this, make sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Comment: As Eric mentioned it would be better for you to share the document. But it seems that you need to use absolute reference in order to "fix" C5 by putting $  =if(C9="","",1+max(C$5:C8))